# Flex Builder 3 Unclosable Editor Windows

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

See: [http://i.imgur.com/pQNQh.png](https://i.imgur.com/pQNQh.png)

Somehow I made this happen and I don't know how to undo it. The image linked above shows my Flex Builder session. The largest section of the window is the editor. Initially, there was a blank window on the screen so I tried closing it, but I couldn't. Then I tried dragging it and realized I could drag it into a corner of itself, hence all the nested windows.

I have no idea how to close these windows or simply reset the view. I went to the preferences under General > Perspectives, but the "reset" button was disabled for every available perspective.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, by dragging windows around you changed the perspective.  This is automatically saved.  You, basically, have to set it back.  But, I'm surprised that the extra "blocks" didn't vanish as you closed stuff.

I have ideas; but I'm not sure what will work, or not.

Open up the File Explorer or package explorer.  "Use that to open up bunch of different files and drag those files into the 'empty' window spaces.

Once all the spots have windows; drag all the files back into one tab.

I think that is harder to explain than it is to actually do.

If you want to try a phone call to address this; we can try screen sharing w/ Connect.   Give me a call at www.asktheflexpert.com .  No charge.

Comment: This was the answer to my question! Thank you!